# How to get the latest posts with a condition within a month in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following posts:

```
title           rating    created_at
-----------------------------------
Post title 1    3         2021-06-21 13:00:19
Post title 2    5         2021-06-16 13:00:19
Post title 3    4         2021-03-21 13:00:19
Post title 4    7         2021-03-18 13:00:19
Post title 5    10        2021-02-26 13:00:19
```

I want to list the latest 3 best rated posts within a month, but there are only 2 posts, so I want to add 1 more.
I want to get this result:

```
Post title 2 - rating 5
Post title 3 - rating 4
Post title 1 - rating 3
```

Is it possible in Laravel?
I use the following code, but it only lists two posts:

```
Post::query()->orderBy('rating', 'desc')
->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
->limit(3)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereBetween` and using carbon `firstOfMonth()` and  `endOfMonth()`

```
Post::orderByDesc('rating')
      ->whereDate('created_at','<=',Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth())
      ->limit(3)
      ->get();
```

Comment: But how to get 2 more if I have only 1 post in this month?

Comment: It only lists 2 post, because the 3th was created 3 months ago, but in this case I want to get 1 more post because I always want to show 3 posts.

Comment: @David.as per your question you wants retrieve post from current month first day but as per comment you have 3 months back then i guess you dont need where condition nor you have to less ->whereDate('created_at','<=',Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth())

Answer (score 0):

try take() instead of limit()

```
Post->orderBy('rating', 'desc')
 ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
 ->take(3)
 ->get();
```